# Cannot parse local JSON Data in the puppeteer-jest test framework?

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs, puppeteer

I need to test the product using Jest+Puppeteer. I locate locators from the front-end in the different location that a Page Object and I need to import that JSON to the Page Object. But when I try to parse using `JSON.parse()` I receive:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

All research all of the question in the Stack Overflow, but nothing is helps.

Page Object:

```
import { waitForNavigation, click, type, pressEnter} from './base';
import { listsPageLocators } from '../constants/locators/listPage.json';

async function clickSearchByCompanyName(page){
    click(page, listsPageLocators.searchByCompanyNameBtn);
    waitForNavigation(page);
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "findNewProspectsBtn" : {
        "locator" : "li.search-leads",
        "name" : "Find New Prospects Button"
    },
    "searchByCompanyNameBtn" : {
        "locator" : "li.company-name > a",
        "name" : "Search By Company Name Button"
    },
    "leadEnrichmentBtn" : {
        "locator" : "li.lead-enrichment",
        "name" : "Lead Enrichment Button"
    },
    "importUrlsBtn" : {
        "locator" : "li.import-urls",
        "name" : "Import URLs Button"
    },
    "listsNameFld" : {
        "locator" : "span.name",
        "name": "List Name Field"
    },
    "searchIndustryOrCompanyField" : {
        "locator" : "input.select2-search__field",
        "name" : "Search Industry Or Company Field"
    },
    "advancedSearchBtn" : {
        "locator" : "a[ng-click='goToAdvancedSearch()']",
        "name" : "Advanced Search Button"
    }
}
```

Base Page Object with click method:

```
async function click(page, JsonObject, text) {
    console.log(JsonObject);
    const locatorData = JSON.parse(JsonObject);
    if (typeof text !== 'undefined') {
        const el = await selectContains(page).getElement(`${locatorData.locator}:contains(${text})`);
        el.click();
        console.log(`Click on ${locatorData.name} which contains ${text}`);
    } else {
        await page.click(locatorData.locator);
        console.log(`Click on ${locatorData.name}`);
    }
}
```

Error:

● Single company page Tests: › C297679 - Open the company page from the list

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

  54 | async function click(page, JsonObject, text) {
  55 |     console.log(JsonObject);
> 56 |     const locatorData = JSON.parse(JsonObject);
     |                              ^
  57 |     if (typeof text !== 'undefined') {
  58 |         const el = await selectContains(page).getElement(`${locatorData.locator}:contains(${text})`);
  59 |         el.click();

  at parse (pages/base.js:56:30)
  at Object.clickViewList (pages/add-company-by-name-popup.js:29:5)
  at Object.clickViewList (company-page-e2e.js:29:35)
```

I expected that can be imported locators from the different JSON and implement it in the page object. But actually, I receive an error.

Comment: The error tells me that the JSON you have is not what it's trying to parse. Can you debug and check exactly what the value of `JsonObject` is.

Comment: I receive that as a JSONobject parameter        
    { locator: 'li.company-name > a',
      name: 'Search By Company Name Button' }

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking that `JsonObject` is already an object and not a JSON formatted string at all and is being coerced in to a string and giving `[object Object]` hence the `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: And how I can get locator value from this? Or can I simplify that `[object Object]` to JSON?

Comment: don't try and parse it: `const locatorData = JsonObject;`. It has already been parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that `JsonObject` is not a JSON formatted string, but a fully fledged JavaScript object. No need to parse just directly assign it.

Change this:

```
const locatorData = JSON.parse(JsonObject);
```

To this:

```
const locatorData = JsonObject;
```

Comment: That is working.
Thank you for help and explanation!